# ActionListener is not abstract and does not override abstract method, but i have a actionPerformed, what is wrong?

Tags: java, oop, actionlistener

I am writing a java program for my OOP class, and i am trying to add some actionlisteners, but for some reason i keep getting this error "BattleshipUI.ExitListener is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener", the following code is how i have my actionlistener constructed.

```
public class ExitListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Are you sure you want to exit?","Exit",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

        if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }


}
```

I have about 4 of these in my code and i am getting the same error on each one.
Any help would be much appreciated.

```html
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
```

Comment: My guess is that you're importing the wrong `ActionEvent` class. Please show your imports.

Comment: i agree with @JonSkeet in addition BattleshipUI.ExitListener it seems your listener is within BattleshipUI class (reason your exitlistener cant be public if that's the case)?

Comment: I believe i found the problem, i was importing "import javafx.event.ActionEvent;" but that should be "import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;" Thanks for having me check that!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `javafx.event.ActionEvent` to `java.awt.event.ActionEvent` in your import or change

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Are you sure you want to exit?","Exit",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

        if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

to

```
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e){
        int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Are you sure you want to exit?","Exit",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

        if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

if you need to keep the `javafx` import.

Comment: I just caught that thanks so much! This was bugging me all of yesterday!